# stock calculation with variant and batches respect to price

Tags: c#, javascript, php, mysql, sql

Checking is the quantity of the items available the user want to sale. User enter the data in the html text boxes like in the following table

```
line    category    itemcode    batch    qty    price    available
1       1           1441341     51-1     12     38.19    11
2       1           9188801     71-2     6      38.19    6
3       2           1404785     16-1     1      134.32   2 
4       1           1488802     38-1     11     38.19    16
5       1           1488801     91-4     20     36.74    11
6       2           1404784     39-1     1      134.32   0
7       1           1472728     60-1     12     38.19    50
8       2           1404786     35-1     1      138.05   0
```

In the above data entry table things not visible to users are:

- category
- available qty

When user enter all the data at the end user validate the entry is all ok

**If the `qty` exceeds the `available` qty (e.g. as on line no 1 there is difference of 1 pcs)**

**Intended behaviour**

1. find where `qty` not greater than `available` qty
2. where `qty` greater than `available` qty, for example like line no 1, then find another item codes with same category and same price)
   For the given example (line 1) `itemcode`'s from the same `category` and same `price` are `9188801` (line 2), `1488802` (line 4) and `1472728` (line 7).  `1488801` (line 5) is not a match due to the price difference, even though it is in the same `category`
3. now listed those items that if they full fill his stock and then also they remain some qty like **line no 7** after **(50-12)=(38)** so now the one pcs not available in **line no 1** will be minus from 38.

**This must be a generic algorithm** because if, by example, on line two if there is `qty` to be minus is 8 not 6 then there is difference of **2 pcs**

The stock deducting would be like so **(50-12)=38 and adjustment for line no 1 (38-1)=37 and then adjustment for line no 2 (37-2)=35**

There will be 5 to 10 item in data entry grid / table of same price and category

You can answer this in any computer language

Comment: I can understand the first part of the requirements above, but the second part regarding the stock deducting e.g. `(50-12)` and `(38-1)` I cannot see where these numbers have been taken from. You might want to select a language which is appropriate for yourself and put down any code you have already tried to demonstrate your understanding and help others guide you further, if you look at [This Guide to Asking Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) you might get more responses to your question.

Comment: Dear sir these numbers get from last column named available in the table

Comment: No worries, it was just unclear as the line numbers referenced didn't correlate with the line number: `line no 1 will be minus from 38` I now see I was just being blind/stupid on the first one (line 7), I'll have another look when I get a minute :-)